# Recursive javascript function will not return to parent call data?

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, fractals

I'm working on an HTML5/JS project to draw a binary fractal tree on a canvas.

HTML5::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <br />
    <script src="tree.js"></script>
    <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="main()">Start</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript::

```
var scale = 0.5;
var min_len = 1;
//setup canvas
var c = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(250, 500);

//returns length of branch
function len(branch) {

    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(branch.len_x, 2) + Math.pow(branch.len_y, 2) );
}

//draws from start to length of branch
function drawBranch(start, branch) {

    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(start.x + branch.len_x, start.y - branch.len_y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

//recursively builds binary fractal tree
function makeChildren(start, theta, parent) {

    if(len(parent) >= min_len) {
        drawBranch(start, parent);

        //linear transformation applied to parent branch which rotates and scales to produce child branch
        child = {len_x: ( parent.len_x * Math.cos(theta) - parent.len_y * Math.sin(theta) ) * scale,
                 len_y: ( parent.len_x * Math.sin(theta) + parent.len_y * Math.cos(theta) ) * scale};

        //recursively build left and right branches of tree
        makeChildren( {x: start.x + parent.len_x, y: start.y - parent.len_y}, theta, child);
        makeChildren( {x: start.x + parent.len_x, y: start.y - parent.len_y}, theta * (-1), child);
    }
}

function main() {

    //initialize tree
    makeChildren( {x: 250, y: 500}, Math.PI / 4, {len_x: 0, len_y: 100} );
}
```

When I run my code it produces a left-ward facing spiral kind of structure (sorry can't post images yet).

The problem is with the length check in the makeChildren function, once the if statement is not longer true i.e. when the branch is too small, the program gets caught in a recursive loop where the size remains too small. Here's the console log of the branch lengths::

[Log] 100 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 49.99999999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 25 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 12.5 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 6.25 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 3.125 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 1.5624999999999998 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

[Log] 0.7812499999999999 (tree.js, line 24)

It should reach the base case for the recursive loop (branch length too small) and return to the previous recursive loop, but it looks like it just keeps checking the same length, 0.78125, over and over again. I can't figure out why, please help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jggz7w9t/1/ logging the inside vs outside of the `if(len(parent) >= min_len)` check reveals that it is indeed not adding more children when the parent length is < min_len

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgJveL?editors=101 is what it does for me. It doesnt loop forever like you are saying. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> checking the same length, 0.78125, over and over again

Each level of recursion doubles the number of calls. It's going to reach that base case like ... 128 (?) times.

> it produces a left-ward facing spiral kind of structure

As it is, there's a single global `child` variable. When the first sub-`makeChild` runs, it reassigns this global `child` variable, and the second sub-`makeChild` starts with this modified one.

You probably wanted

```
var child = {len_x: ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLxe4fx1/

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, but it's still only drawing half the tree, I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: well you only call `makeChildren` once in `main`

Answer (score 0):

I reached the same conclusion but guest was faster than me :) To know why this happens remember that  [Objects are Passed by Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.as) and as `child` was undefined it was on the global [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Another jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6pjduncg/